# Can the Carvain caravan be saved?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently encountered Plautis Carvain and company on the road one night.

According to UESP:

> When approached and spoken to, he claims he is traveling to the wedding of an important Imperial personage and is carrying several rich gifts to give her.
>
>  After defeating the dragon of Mount Anthor, Plautis can be encountered traveling through the wilderness still in the company of his wife Salonia Carvain. When approached and spoken to, however, he claims that they had been robbed by bandits and their bodyguard eaten by a dragon and that they never made it to the wedding.

However, I wonder if they could be saved from this fate by having the Dovahkiin as a bodyguard.  Obviously there is no dialogue for this, but I did manage to shadow them long enough to save them the trouble of a couple wolf packs, a thief, and a sabre cat.  When I realized they had passed two road signs saying they were going in the *wrong direction* though, I gave up.

Has anyone tried following them around and protecting them long enough to see if they could eventually make it to their destination?

Comment: The wrong direction bit made me laugh. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possibile, as this isn't a quest but only a couple of random NPCs throwed in for immersion, just like the Kahjit caravans.

Comment: The Khajiit caravans actually have a purpose though, since you can trade with them.

Comment: As the marriage caravan, since an evil character can kill and steal from them. I really don't see any other options, since it's a random scripted event with no link whatsoever.

Comment: PNGs? You mean NPCs?

Comment: Sorry, Italian took over once again (PNGs is NPCs translated in Italian). Yeah, NPCs :P